# How to "npm start" with supervisord?

Tags: node.js, npm, supervisord

I have a simple question. How does a supervisord config look like to start an express app?

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:sshd]
command=/usr/sbin/sshd -D

[programm:api]
directory=/var/www/my_api
command=npm start
```

I also tried with:

```
[programm:api]
command=node /var/www/my_api/app.js
```

However it does not start and no errors are logged. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A typo was causing the problem

```
[programm:api]
```

is wrong. Right:

```
[program:api]
```